# Updated Xcode complaining about update on different user accounts, same Mac

Tags: macos, xcode

On my Mac I have two accounts: one is mine and the another my wife's. I have the latest Xcode version but when my wife logs in, she has a notification about an update. When it opens the AppStore there's an Xcode actualization available. When I try to update I get an error saying there's no enough space. I don't know how to deal with this issue and I wonder why there's an update at all if I have it up to date in the other account?

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Does your wife use Xcode?

Comment: No, she doesn’t